# What is the standard guidelines for activity creation in Clearcase UCM?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

What is the standard guidelines for activity creation?

In our team, all team members are creating activities by their own. 
It is not being assigned by team leader. Is it possible to create an activity by team leader then assign it to members?

How to achieve it?

Comment: Do you use ClearQuest? If so - UCM-enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways you could go.

ClearCase (stand alone):

A trigger can enforce, the activity or the naming of the activity but this can require intial development of trigger and script & also the maitenance. You may also go part way in which you enforce the prefix to be ENH_* or DEF_* or CR_*. You can even check to see if total activity is in a list of strings you specify...limited to your need.

Alternative (ClearCase with integration):

What you may be looking for is a higher level order, I had created such a system with ClearCase integrated to ClearQuest. Developers are assigned "WorkRequests" (e.g. Defects / Enhancements) These can be directly assigned, tracked and added to builds.

In essence you use the record ID acts node that holds all activities checked in by developer. You can report/slice/dice with activitis and checkin refs as you want)
In this model you control the assigned record not the activity (but they can be the same!  ie. raised records with known activties in advance and assign them.)

Regards

Jim2

Comment: I also forgot to mention the "trust with checkup" approach which would be to assume developers know their activities and and to report and all activities in your change set that match the "build activity list" anything outside this is queried ..problem with this approach is that UCM deliveries and not easily rolled back...you need to evaluate...

Answer (score 1):

No, the usual practice is that usually one would select an activity he/she created when checking in new versions.
The "[`setactivity`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setactivity.htm)" doesn't list any restriction in term of Identity when selecting the activity to use.

An activity is here to group some tightly linked changes together, changes being new versions on files or directories for a given component on a given stream.

There is no real "standard guidelines" except to keep linked changes together.

You could prevent the creation of activity (except for a project manager) with a pre-op trigger though.
I suppose another trigger might be able to enforce the selection of an activity only by a specific resource, emulating that way the "assignment" process.

But I rarely seen that implemented (or only when use with a link with ClearQuest).